# From a math Professor, Bernard Budiansky

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What is next in the sequence?

50, 42, 34, 28, 23, 18,14, ?

Comment: I will guess 10 or 11.

Comment: No, sorry.  That's not it.

Comment: 59?...........................

Comment: Had anyone heard of this one before?

Comment: I remember my father stumping me with this one when I was young.  Not really fair, since he grew up in New York City, and I didn't...

Comment: In some ways it's not fair, but no worse than say, 3,3,5,4,4,3,5,5,4,?

Comment: @Jiminion 3,6,6,8... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shamefully relying on Len's spoiler,

> the sequence is stops on the New York subway's 1 line

and given that

> Jiminion didn't specify that the next item in the sequence was a *number*

next must be

> "Christopher". (The stop is at Christopher Street, and the previous items in the sequence omitted "street".)

Comment: I suggest losing the extra word as it wasn't included in the original sequence...

Comment: @Joffan Fair enough, that's more elegant.

Comment: Good job! If nothing else, I guess this question got some folks to google Bernie Budiansky, who was a great guy.

Comment: Jiminion - make sure to select this answer as the correct one to give reo his credit!

Answer (score 8):

Considering Bernard Budiansky is from:

> New York City and the reverse sequence shows up in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=14%2C18%2C23%2C28%2C34%2C42%2C50&sort=&language=english&go=Search):
>  the sequence is **local stops on New York City Broadway line (IRT #1) subway**
>
>  There is **no "next number"** in the sequence.

Comment: "What is next in the sequence?"